# Finding first Sunday of the month is not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find first Sunday of the month.  tried with next_day function which produced proper result, but if the first day of the month is a Sunday then it doesn't work.

```
select next_day(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),'sun') first_sun
from dual 

select next_day(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),'sun') first_sun
from dual
```

I'm running the query with the date `sysdate='2019-09-10'` which shows the 2nd Sunday instead of the 1st Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

Just go back a day after truncating, so you find the first Sunday after the last day of the previous month:

```
select next_day(trunc(sysdate,'MM') - 1,'sun') first_sun from dual;

FIRST_SUN 
----------
2019-09-01
```

Comment: Thank you for your spontaneous reply it working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You happen to land on month when Sunday is also the first day in month,

[NEXT_DAY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions093.htm) uses **later than** date, therefore you will have to check from previous day for example

```
select next_day(trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1,'SUNDAY') first_sun from dual;
```

> NEXT_DAY returns the date of the first weekday named by char that is **later than** the date date.

Comment: Thank you for your spontaneous reply it working fine.

Comment: @I.Sharma - [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)